# Nested Json from nested mysql queries in Nodejs/ExpressJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, express

I m fetching data from mysql database in nodejs/expressjs and want to create nested json from it.

I want to create Json object like this :

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "countryName": "USA",
    "population": 10000,
    "cities": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "cityName": "NY",
        "countryId": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "cityName": "Chicago",
        "countryId": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "countryName": "Canada",
    "population": 20000,
    "cities": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "cityName": "Toronto",
        "countryId": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "cityName": "Ottawa",
        "countryId": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

here is my code in expressJs but it is giving me an empty array of JSON

```
app.get("/checkJson",function(req,res){
  var country = {};

var outerobj = {};
 var outerArray = [];

   conn.query("select * from country",function(err,result){
     for(var i = 0 ;i<result.length;i++){
        var cityobj = {};
        var city = [];
       conn.query("select * from city where countryId ="+result[i].id,function(err,cityResult){
         for(var j = 0;j<cityResult.length;j++){
           cityobj = {cityName:cityResult[j].name,countryId:cityResult[j].countryId};
           city.push(cityobj);
         } //end  city forloop

       }) //end city Query

       outerobj = {id:result[i].id,countryName:result[i].name,pop:result[i].population,cities:city};
       outerArray.push(outerobj);

     } //end country forloop
   }) // end country query
   console.log(outerArray);
})
```

Comment: In Javascript all the action happens in callbacks. The `console.log()` call at your sample's end is invoked before your first query completes, never mind your nested queries.

One way to handle this situation is using async / await (or Promises). Explaining that is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer, sorry to say.

Comment: can you provide me a link or something from where i can learn about it ?

Comment: Suggestion:  use your favorite search engine to look for *nodejs mysql promise*. You'll find many helpful resources.

Comment: Thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL returns flat objects. We want to nest joined objects.

Let's say we have courses table, each course belongs to a department and has various course sections. We would like to have a resulting courses array that has a department object property within it and have a list of course sections.

This is a good solution from kyleladd on github

https://github.com/ravendano014/node-mysql-nesting

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." See [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)